# validate minimum number in an angular form field only if a value is presented

Tags: angular, angular-forms, angular8

I'm writing an angular 8 web application with angular material and forms.

I created a `FormGroup` with `FormBuilder` and added validations to the fields.

I have a field with `Validators.min(0)`. the thing is that this field is not mandatory, so I want to validate that the value is minimum zero only if there is a value there to begin with.

how do I achieve that ?

ahhm.. ok this is how I built the form

```
  this.queryForm = this.formBuilder.group({
            ...
            durationLongerThenInSec: ['', Validators.min(0)],
        });
    }
```

thanks!

Comment: If it's not mandatory, do not add validators to it!

Comment: @nircraft - ahhmm.. if people do add values.. i wanna check that they are valid.

Comment: i think i'll just write my own min validator that provides an error if it's not null and not in the range of values that I allow. I assumed angular had something like that

Comment: `durationLongerThenInSec: ['', [Validators.min(0)]],` should work. It doesn't check for rtequired attribute.. but once touched and new value entered it should trigger the min validation.

Comment: create a [custom validator](https://angular.io/guide/form-validation#custom-validators)

Comment: @nircraft - thanks unfortunately it provides the same results. I'll just write a custom validator. thanks

Comment: @ufk, do you have the error display in template?

Comment: can you share your input html tag as well

Comment: @nircraft - whoops you are awesome! you where right, it does work! I had a dirty check bug that didn't send my form, this is valid. please post it as answer i'll accept it.

Comment: @ufk, thanks. added the answer. Please accept

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you do not have `Validators.required` the required validation will not be applied to your form control.
You should try to add `Validators.min(0)` to form control and it will validate if it's dirty and satisfies the min value rule:

```
this.queryForm = this.formBuilder.group({
            ...
            durationLongerThenInSec: ['', [Validators.min(0)]],
        });
    }
```

Also make sure that you have the error display on template to handle and show error message when `durationLongerThenInSec.errors.min` is available:

```
<p *ngIf="durationLongerThenInSec.errors?.min">error message</p>
```